# supplicant connection change doesn't trigger

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi

I want to do something when the wifi connection is established.
I have a BroadcastReceiver that works prefectly receiving NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION and SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION, but not SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION. This one is harder to test: I turn off/on the router for that.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
            intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
            intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
            registerReceiver(receiverWifi, intentFilter);
    //...
    }

     class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
            public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
                final String action = intent.getAction();

                Log.d("mhp","*BroadcastReceiver: " + action")}
```

And the Manifiest.xml

```
  <application
        a..
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

And the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
  <application
        a..
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.SCAN_RESULTS" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On connecting to wifi network even if you don't get `SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION`, you will definitely get `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` and you can play with this action for all your needs.

In the broadcast receiver, do this:

```
String action = intent.getAction();
if (WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action))
{
    NetworkInfo netInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if ( (netInfo.getDetailedState()==(NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED)) )
    {
        // your wifi is connected, do what you want to do
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @unrealsoul007. It doesn't solve the supplicant mystery, but it fulfill my needs!

Comment: @Sorrentum Glad to help!! Happy coding..!! :)

Comment: even though it might suit his needs, from my tests we never get anything other than DISCONNECTED, ASSOCIATING, ASSOCIATED and COMPLETED. Any attempt to debug connection failures such as no transitions to/from AUTHENTICATING, GROUP_HANDSHAKE, FOUR_WAY_HANDSHAKE, will never ever occur on a Nexus 5... WifiInfo.getDetailedStateOf(supplicantState) will be OBTAINING_IPADDR 24/7 on the same phone, even though there's an IP and even internet...